# Formatting a column of List in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class as below from which i have generated a list A.
The Decimal part of the property in the new list i want it to be string so that i can round that column to 2 decimal places from my another function-MakeMoney

Any idea how the new list can be used with decimal rounded to 2 places?
I tried putting the convert.tostring(Decimal value) in the list with linq but it does not work.

```
public class Payment
{
    {
        public int Period { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }

    List<Payment> A = new List<Payment>
    {
        new Payment { Period =1, Balance = 10.5689 },
        new Payment { Period =2, Balance = 12.56896 },
        new Payment { Period =3, Balance = 45.156 },
        new Payment { Period =4, Balance = 23.56465 },
        new Payment { Period =5, Balance = 36.65465 },
        new Payment { Period =6, Balance = 45.5646 }
    };

         public  String MakeMoney(string variant)
        {
            String _denom = "$ 0.00";
            try
            {
                variant = variant.Replace("$", ""); //In case if Currency is supplied.
                if (variant != "")
                {
                    decimal _decimal = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(variant)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    if (_decimal >= 0)
                        _denom = "$ " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", _decimal);
                    else
                        _denom = " -$ " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", Math.Abs(_decimal));

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error in conversion- Function-MakeNumber Value:" + variant + ":" + ex.ToString());
            }
            return _denom;
        }

    DataGrodView1DataSource= (from row in A select new {row.Period,MakeMoney(Convert.ToString(row.Balance))}).ToList();
}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: "does not work"... What is the error?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just leave it as a decimal and round it instead of converting it to a string and then converting it back to a decimal and round it?

Comment: I don't even see where the function MakeMoney is called from :-)

Comment: I just added MakeMoney for the Balance column. xanatos. It gives - Invalid anonymous type member declarator.

Comment: The reason i need to put in string is because i need to display the type of currency as well.

Comment: Can't you just make an overload for `MakeMoney(Decimal )` to take in a decimal, convert that to string and then call the original you wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name the property used to store MakeMoney method result:

```
DataGrodView1DataSource = (from row in A select new {row.Period, Money = MakeMoney(Convert.ToString(row.Balance))}).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome!! Mr Singh thats exactly what i was looking for. Probably using new keyword it creates a new column which now i also realized from your answer.!

Comment: The `new` keyword actually creates an anonymous object. However, you just needed to store the result in a property as you're **assigning** the value from an expression, the compiler needs a property name to assign to.